# jQuery call same function when two different buttons are clicked

Tags: jquery, function

I have a button with class `try` and when its clicked there is a function that is being called, now I want to create a button called `start` that will do the same, and I don't want to copy paste whole code in that button click handler, is there a way to say lets say if `try` or `start` do the following in jquery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that since you said `a button called start` that `start` is the id. That is why I am using a `#` instead of a `.` to reference it.

```
$('.try, #start').click(function(e){
    YourFunction();
});
```

if `start` is the class, then use this. `#` indicates an id, while `.` indicates a class.

```
$('.try, .start').click(function(e){
    YourFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the handler code to a named function and bind the named function.

```
function someFunction() {
}

$('.try').on('click', someFunction);
$('.start').on('click', someFunction);
```

Or in one line,

```
$('.try, .start').on('click', someFunction);
```

Comment: 2 individual calls instead of using the `$('.try, #start')` selector? Any reason for that?

Comment: too much writing, @Dutchie432 had the simplest answer

Comment: @Dutchie432 Even though, I updated my post to have it in one line. I personally prefer having it in 2 lines as it looks more clear.

Comment: @Grigor Its more of a preference than writing. Again, it may be just me. Btw, For your case [Mark's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10419464/297641) is my recommendation.

Comment: @Vega if you can write less and do more, I don't think there is a reason not to, the other method is cleaner too.

Comment: @Grigor It is just my personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.start, .try').click(function(){
//do your thing here
});
```

assumes two buttons with different classes:

```
<button class='try'>try</button>
<button class='start'>start</button>
```

MUCH easier if you use one class:

```
<button class='trystart'>try</button>
<button class='trystart'>start</button>

$('.trystart').click(function(){
//do your thing here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just do:

```
$('#start, .try').on('click', function(){ // both of them
   myFunction();
});
```

or:

```
$('#start').on('click', function(){
   $('.try').click();         // trigger .try action
});
```

---

Or just call your function inside the click:

```
function myClickFunction(){
   // your code ...
}

$('#start').on('click',function(){
   myClickFunction();
});
```

Comment: it is not a function, it is code executed when a button is clicked that I can't put in a function

Comment: than use my second example! `$('#start').on('click', function(){
   $('.try').click();         // trigger .try action
});` This will trigger the code inside the `.fun` element, just like you you actually clicked the `.try` ! fun.